# Hangouts Chat: how to retrieve project_id or client_id in incoming event request?

Tags: hangouts-api

I have setup a fully operational chat bot in Hangouts Chat orchestrated by a tailored webserver. I would like now to be able to have this webserver to interact with other Hangouts bots that I created and to route some requests to some of my other servers that will have to know which bots initiated the event.
With other provider, such as Slack, the app_id is provided in the event request data.
But with hangouts, this is not the case. I could not find any data in the request body or headers that represent either project_id or client_id.
In a more simple way my question is : "How to identify the Hangouts bot that send me an event request?" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One month later, I finally found the time to answer my question :)

In order to identify the Hangouts project that is calling your server, when you receive an event from Hangouts Chat, you'll find in the incoming request the header `Authorization` whose value is something like `Bearer abcd1234`.
If you decode this JWToken (ie, `abcd1234` in our example), in the resulting data, you'll have a field `aud` which is exactly the "project number" of your Hangouts app. This "project number" can be found at "https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?project=referenceofyourprojecthere".

Answer (score 0):

An event request's response will contain an [Event instance](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/Event) in its body, which one of its fields will be an [User object](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/User).  That User object will contain a `name` field that will represent the user's id (whether it's a human or a bot).

It will look like this:

```js
{
  "name": "users/<id>",
  "displayName": "<name that appears in the chat>",
  "type": "BOT" 
}
```

Comment: Thx for your reply. This is true when the bot send a message but in most of the case, we want to be noticed when the user talks to our bots. And when this is the cas (ie, a user that causes the event "MESSAGE" to be emitted) the message.sender User instance refers to the "HUMAN" user and not the bot. So I cannot know to which of my bots the user is talking to. But thanks to you I found the solution, because your reply made me dive again in this issue and found my answer in headers... see my own reply ;)

Comment: Hey! I'm glad you could find the solution by yourself and with a little help from my answer, please consider post your solution as an answer with an explanation so other people which have the same problem could solve it, too